# Forming a "habitual" sentence: "I usually get up at 7.15"

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 私は**大抵**七時十五分に起きます

Would this be a correct way to say 'I **usually** get up at 7.15'? Not sure 大抵 is correctly placed before the time+に

Comment: What would make you think that this sentence is correct/natural? What would make you think that this sentence is incorrect/unnatural? I think you could ask a much better question than provide one translation of a sentence and asking if it is correct. You could, for example, look up different ways of saying "usually" and ask how to choose among those. As it stands, the question will likely get closed as a translation check/request without prior research effort.

Comment: My textbook says に is used with specific times,days,etc but not with frequency words, so I'm not sure if it can be placed in that position in the sentence, right before the time+に

Comment: I see. Could you revise your question to include your explanation? Also, since you're asking about に, I would remove the [phrase] tag and add [particle-ni] and [grammar].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can place frequency words like たいてい, いつも, 普通, 普段 etc. before "time+に".

> 私はたいてい７時１５分に起きます。
>   私は[普通]{ふつう}７時１５分に起きます。
>   私は[普段]{ふだん}７時１５分に起きます。
>   etc.

For more examples, see [Weblio辞書usuallyを含む例文一覧](http://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/usually/7)

Comment: ありがとう for the clear answer :)